# converting a string to date in php

Tags: php, date

I have a string that contains date and time. Format of my string is `yyyymmddtime`.
For example. `20171125123000209`. this is my complete string in which first comes the month, then month and then day after that time. How can i retrieve date from it by converting to readable date format. I tried with php's date function. But the output was not as expected. Please help.

Comment: So you say that is in the format of `yyyymmddtime` ... but the `time` portion doesnt seem to add up. `20171125123000209` = `year 2017, month 11, day 25, hour 12, minute 30, wat 00209(!?)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
  $str_date= "20171125123000209";
  $exiting_date_format='Ymd';
  //first 8 characters from given date string in second parameter below
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($exiting_date_format, substr($str_date,0,8));
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//specify desired date format
?>
```

**Output :**

```
2017-11-25
```

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) - Parses a time string according to a specified format

Comment: Cleaner just to write `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', substr($str_date,0,8));` ... preg_match is overkill ;) However this is actually an answer that will get the question asker what they wanted.

Comment: thanks, using `substr` will be efficient here, as we want only one string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date() function of php

```
<?php
  $full_date= "20171125123000209";
  echo date('dS F h:i:s A', $full_date);
  //Output = 31st May 12:30:09 AM
?>
```

**Or,**

To get date from timestamp  like now,

```
 $timestamp= time(); //Or your timestamp here
 $date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp); //Inside first parameter, give your date format
 echo $date; //17-12-2017
```

**Or,**

To get anything from string you can also use substr() function of php.

```
<?php
  $full_date= "20171125123000209";
  $year = substr($full_date, 0, 4);
  $month = substr($full_date, 4, 2);
  $date = substr($full_date, 6, 2);

  echo 'Year = '.$year.' ';
  echo 'Month = '.$month.' ';
  echo 'Date = '. $date.' ';
?>
```

**Output:**
Year = 2017 Month = 11 Date = 25

[Test in jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/huK)

[About substr() function in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: i tried echo date('dS F h:i:s A', $full_date); this one. instead of getting 25th November, am getting 17th march

Comment: How do you get the string 20171125123000209 ? I think thats look like a timestamp 12201701970 Or a complete date format ... You may better use substr() to retrieve the date and any others from the string.

Comment: $timestamp= time();
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
echo $date; //Output = 17-12-2017

Comment: this is a system generated time. the format is same as i said in the question.

Comment: So from the string first get only the timestamp using substr() then using that timestamp you can do any date() function. Timestamp example is also given here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to manipulate the string at all. PHP's `DateTime` class supports parsing a string containing miliseconds natively, using the `u` format modifier:

```
$str = '20171125123000209';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHisu', $str);
```

Using your new `$date` object, you can convert to whatever format you're looking for, e.g.

```
echo $date->format("F j Y, g:i a");
// November 25 2017, 12:30 pm
```

See https://eval.in/920636

Answer (score -1):

```
$your_strtotime_val = ""; //20171125123000209
$convert_to_date = date("m-d-Y h:i:s",$your_strtotime); // [m-d-Y h:i:s] this depending on how you convert date in first time so be careful
```

Comment: Heh... the second argument for `date` is supposed to be a TIMESTAMP. `20171125123000209` is NOT a timestamp.